# dropdownlist disable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

when admin approve/reject any document once then when admin again login then he/she not be able to approve/reject documents again and dropdownlist will be disabled only for those documents which can be once approve/reject then when admin view any new documents then drop down will be enable and when  admin  approve/reject this document then  it will  be disable dropdownlist for not approve /reject again

for this i do this

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Find the DropDownList in the Row

        DropDownList abc = (e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList9") as DropDownList);
        abc.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

but this code show me all dropdownlist are disable .

any solution how i will do this?

Comment: You really should reword this post.  That is one long run-on sentence.

Comment: What is your datasource - DataSet, DataTable or IEnumerable? Please post your datasource.

Comment: i can show data from table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, I assume your DataSource is either DataTable or DataSet.

If so, you want to cast **DataItem** to **DataRowView** inside **RowDataBound Event** to get the value of the status column.

[image]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList9">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Approve" Value="1" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" selected="selected" Value="3">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof (int));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof (string));
        table.Columns.Add("ApproveID", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(1, "Jon Doe", "1");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "Eric Newton", "2");
        table.Rows.Add(3, "Marry Doe", "3");

        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var item = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        var dropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList9") as DropDownList;

        // Get value from ApproveID column, 
        // and check whehter Approve, Reject or others.
        switch (item["ApproveID"].ToString())
        {
            case "1":
            case "2":
                dropDownList.Enabled = false;
                break;
            default:
                dropDownList.Enabled = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanku for ur reply but it show me error "Status is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table."

Comment: The above code is for demonstration purpose only. **You will need to replace the column based on your application.** Mostly likely it will be **ApproveID**. See my updated answer.

Comment: when admin view new document then this  dropdownlist is disable but how i enable this when admin view new documnet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the data item from each row, I am assuming it is available on the object your are binding to the grid, and determine if they have been approved / rejected. If so then you should run you logic to disable:

```
        protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                var yo = (YOUR-OBJECT)e.Row.DataItem;

                if(yo.Status !== null OR yo.Status != 'Not Reviewed'){
                //Find the DropDownList in the Row
                DropDownList abc = (e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList9") 
                as  DropDownList);
                abc.Enabled = false;

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: what is "(YOUR-OBJECT)"??

Comment: Whatever object he is binding to this grid, not provided

Answer (score 0):

you can ask on which row you are with this code:

```
if (e.Row.RowIndex == <aRowNumber>)
{
    ...
}
```